# Java - SWT - New runnable upon clicking submit button

Tags: java, swt, runnable

I'm getting the dreaded...

```
Exception in thread "Controller Thread" org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
```

Quick overview of what I am trying to accomplish:

I have a listener on the Submit button, I would like to start a new thread due to the amount of processing the app will do with various url's.

This is part of my code in the Submit button listener...

```
submitButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
                try {
                    // Check to see if http field is valid
                    httpValid = checkHttp(http);
                    if (httpValid) {
                        Thread t = new Thread(new UIMain(), "Controller Thread");
                        t.start();      
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Not a Valid http");
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

Here is my run method...

```
public void run() {
        options = new Options();
        setOptions(options);
        Controller run = new Controller(options);
    }
```

The error points to line "setOptions(options)"
options is a object, holding some data from the SWF fields that the user will input. setOptions is fairly straight forward, in that function, I gather the data from the SWF fields, and set them in the object.

Let me know if I need to post any more code...

Example of some code I'm doing in setOptions(options)...

```
String url = http.getText();
options.addUrl(url);
```

Thanks,

Comment: Then the error is exactly what it says.  You have one GUI thread already(the button being pressed), and you're spawning a new thread that's a GUI window.  This is explicitly not allowed with swt.  Your spawned thread will have to use Display.asyncExec() or syncExec() when dealing with gui objects.

Comment: @Whnunlife you should accept an answer if it helped you to solve the problem, even though it isn't perfect...

Answer (score 2):

You can not access the SWT UI straightly from a separate thread. What you should rather do is perform an async invocation from that separate thread using the Display API.

Example:

```
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // access the SWT UI
    }
});
```

Comment: Okay, so this is the same for just reading the values of the fields correct? As of right now, I'm not trying to update any elements in the SWT display, just create a new thread to do some heavy processing.

Comment: as per my understanding you should never access the SWT UI straight from a separate thread, it doesn't matter whether is for reading or writing values as SWT UI runs in its own thread. If you just need the values to start a heavy process why don't you initialise the thread after obtaining the values from the UI?

Comment: Okay, let me give that a shot

Comment: We'll, I think it's working. This is what I have...

[code]
httpValid = checkHttp(http);
if (httpValid) {
options = new Options();
setOptions(options);
run = new Controller(options);
Thread t = new Thread(new UIMain(), "Controller Thread");
t.start();  
} else {
System.out.println("Not a Valid http");
}[/code]

and in the run thead...

[code]public void run() {
main(null);
}[/code]

Comment: great, as you don't need to perform any modifications in the UI from that separate thread the best option is to initialise the thread with the values it needs instead of doing that from the thread.